# Performing Detailed Profiling of Java Running in Oracle11g Database

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to perform detailed profiling of a java app that's been loaded into Oracle11g running with OJVM.  I'm able to connect the JMX agent within oracle to enable JConsole to attach for some preliminary monitoring but I'm looking to go deeper as part of investigating some performance issues.  So I have 2 questions...

1) Within JConsole when the Oracle JMX Agent is started, there is an OracleRuntime MBean which has a dumpAllHeaps operation...this generations a .DMP and a .TBL in the directory specified to the MBean operation.  What is the mechanism for viewing the contents of these files? Trying to import using Oracle results in a IMP-00037: Character set marker unknown error.  I've not found any documentation on this from Oracle.

2) What other methods exist to perform a heap dump against the OJVM jvm if any?  I've tried jmap and some other methods but with no luck.

For info...this is an Oracle 11 running JServer VM Version 1.5.0_01.

I feel like I'm missing an obvious detail here...

Comment: are you using MAT to look at the dumps?  http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Comment: No, the produced .dmp files are an Oracle proprietary format as best I can tell, it's not a HPROF dump file.  MAT doesn't know how to read, it throws an exception.  I've tried every typical tool to view the files like MAT, JProfiler and the standard ones included with the JDK (jhat, visualvm, etc).  But no luck...they're not able to read the contents.